# R simple duck-typed objects with methods

Tags: r, oop

I want to do a very simple thing in R - have an algorithm I can easily parametrize with a set of functions. I was pretty sure I could do something like duck-typed objects. Here's the idea shown on very simple code:

```
par1.generate <- function(n) {
  runif(n, min=0, max=1000)
}

par1.mean <- function(vec) {
  mean(vec)
}


par2.generate <- function(n) {
  round(runif(n, min=0, max=1000))
}

par2.mean <- function(vec) {
  mean(vec, trim=0.2)
}

#the "algorithm"

alg <- function(par) {
  v <- par.generate(10)
  par.mean(v)
}

alg(par1)
alg(par2)
```

If I tried to run this code I would get something like

> Error in alg(par1) : could not find function "par.mean"

So I guess my intuitive approach doesn't work.

What is the R way of doing something like that? The task is simple, so I would prefer the syntax to be as simple as possible - no abstract classes or similar.

Comment: Might I suggest you go read up on "S3" classes.  They're very, very easy to create, but it does require *some* effort.  Specifically, you have to create a default function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use list of functions.

```
par1 <- list(generate=par1.generate,mean=par1.mean)
par2 <- list(generate=par2.generate,mean=par2.mean)

alg <- function(par) {
  v <- par$generate(10)
  par$mean(v)
}

alg(par1)
[1] 495.2501
alg(par2)
[1] 481
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `match.fun` and pass the names as strings:

```
alg <- function(par) {
    v <- (match.fun(paste(par,"generate",sep=".")))(10)
    (match.fun(paste(par,"mean",sep=".")))(v)
}
```

I get:

```
# > alg("par1")
# [1] 615.5656
# > alg("par2")
# [1] 509
```

There are some more sophisticated options, using expressions and symbols, i.e. computing on the language. Please tell if you are interested in such things and we can help more.

Comment: I don't really like this solution since its idea is similar to an `eval()` or a `#define`, but I can see it's something I could use really quick.

Answer (score 1):

The S3 style function dispatch is indeed somewhat reminiscent of duck-typing. You can define a generic function name ("sound" in the example below), and override different functions for each class. Depending on the class attribute of the argument, R will select the appropriate function. Read up on UseMethod in particular, which is the center of R's function dispatch mechanism.

Example adapted from http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-s3-oop-system/:

```
# Set up dispatch for the generic function sound: 
sound <- function(x) UseMethod("sound", x)

# Methods are defined with a naming convention: method.class:
# This defines the method sound on class dog:
sound.dog <- function(x) "bark"
# Same for cow:
sound.cow <- function(x) "moo"
# Fallback:
sound.default <- function(x) "animal sound"

# The methods function can find out which classes a generic function was designed for:
> methods("sound")
[1] sound.cow     sound.default sound.dog

# R looks for methods in the order in which they appear in the class vector until it found the appropriate method to operate on.
# This makes multiple-inheritance possible

> x <- structure("cat", class = c("cat", "dog", "cow"))
> sound(x)
[1] "bark"
```

But it seems to me you are trying to wish for language features that R doesn't have. R is quirky and sometimes there just isn't a pretty way of doing things.